# Active Record Associations not working when I use the where query

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three tables User, Book and Author. One User has_many Books and each Book has_one Author in this case, so when I perform a query like

```
user_book = Books.find_by_user_id(user.id)
user_book.name
> "Moby Dick"
user_book.author.name
> "Herman Melville"
```

But the problem is when I try to get more than one book with a "where" query to iterate each one

```
user_books = Books.where(user_id: user.id)
user_books[0].name
> "Moby Dick"
user_books[0].author
> NoMethodError: undefined method `author' for nil:NilClass
user_books[0].author.name
> NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

Should I guess the model association is lost when I use the 'where' query ?
How I can obtain multiple records without lost that association that permit to use related table objects directly?

Comment: I don't think the association is being lost here, but your code sample of the problem looks incomplete. `NoMethodError: undefined method `author' for nil:NilClass` means that the object you're calling `author` on is actually nil, but since you're calling it on `user_books[0]` and that was demonstrated not to be nil in the line above, it doesn't make sense for it now to be nil. Can you paste the code demonstrating the error straight out of Rails console?

Comment: Corrected console output. @RobertNubel

Comment: What's the SQL generated with this code `Books.where(user_id: user.id)`? (You can get it by doing `Books.where(user_id: user.id).to_sql`)

Comment: Hi @SebastianPalma, this is the sql :  `"SELECT \"books\".* FROM \"books\" WHERE \"books\".\"user_id\" = 4"`

Comment: And the SQL generate by `user_books[0].author`?

Comment: It looks to me like you just have a Book in your database with a nil author_id. If you don't want to allow that, add a presence validation to Book (e.g. `validates :author, presence: true`), then reset your DB or fix the invalid records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @RobertNubel , I found the problem was a nil author_id and the lack of validation on Book model.